# Is the state of Smart Contract variables only changed after a block?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mining, contract-design, remix

Assuming I have a Smart Contract with this code:

```
contract TestContract {
  uint256 var1 = 0;

  function test()
  {
     if (var1 == 0)
     {
        var1 = 1;
        throw;
     }
  }
}
```

Assuming **2 different addresses** call the test() function **in the same block**, will both transactions get the throw or only the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All calls to `test()` will throw with that program. When a transaction throws, all state changes are reversed, so `var1` will always stay 0.

If you write it like this:

```
contract TestContract {
  uint256 var1 = 0;

  function test()
  {
     if (var1 == 0)
     {
        var1 = 1;
     }
     else
     {
        throw;
     }
  }
}
```

...the first call to `test()` will change `var1` from `0` to `1`

and all subsequent calls to `test()` will throw.

Even if the are in the same block.

The state of the smart contract is changed after each transaction, not only after each block.